# Buffer is not defined exception while connecting WebRTC to Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, webrtc

I am trying to connect webRTC to a Vue 3 project. I define global and after that i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined" which i don't know how to fix. How can i fix it?

https://github.com/homepirate/rutconf_frontend

Here is the main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import components from "@/components/UI";
import router from "@/router/router.js";
import store from "@/store";
import VueWebRTC from 'vue-webrtc'


const app = createApp(App);
components.forEach((component) => {
  app.component(component.name, component);
});

app
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .use(VueWebRTC)
  .mount("#app");
```

After doing that i get "ReferenceError: global is not defined". Then i fix it adding global to vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
   
   import { defineConfig } from "vite";
   import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

   const fs = require('fs');
   
   
   export default defineConfig({
     plugins: [vue()],
     define: {
       global: {},
     },
     server: {
      https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
      },
     },
     resolve: {
       alias: {
         "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
       },
     },
   });
```

But after that i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined" which i don't know how to fix. How do i fix it?

Comment: It seems you are using Vite while the package is configured to be used with Webpack.
Also, seems the package is not Vue-3 friendly.
https://github.com/westonsoftware/vue-webrtc/blob/master/sample/package.json